# Saving string array to user defaults

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have read all the stackoverflow articles I could find about this but doing what they said for some reason does not work.

I would like to save an array of strings (1 string at a time) to user defaults then print out the entire array for my own sanity.

The output of my code is always "allItems array is empty".

Here is my code, thank you:

```
    // new string to save
    let newAddition = "new string"
    
    // retrieve all items in array from userdefaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var allItems = defaults.array(forKey: "Key") as? [String]

    // add new item
    allItems?.append(newAddition)

    // re-save the plan array
    defaults.set(allItems, forKey: "Key")
    
    printItems()


func printItems() {
    
    // retrieve all items in array from userdefaults
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let allItems = defaults.array(forKey: "Key") as? [String] ?? []

    if allItems.count != 0 {
        for plan in 0 ..< (allItems.count-1) {
            print("item name: \(plan)")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("allItems array is empty")
    }

}
```

Comment: `for plan in 0 ..< (allItems.count-1)`  this will skip the last item. Are you sure that this is intentional? If you would like to iterate all elements (indices) of your collection just use `for index in allItems.indices`

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
var allItems = defaults.array(forKey: "Key") as? [String]
```

returns nil initially, and you never create a new, empty array in this case.

Replace it with:

```
var allItems = defaults.array(forKey: "Key") as? [String] ?? []
```

to do so.

Also, this: `for plan in 0 ..< (allItems.count-1)` is an error. `..<` already excludes the end of the range, so use `for plan in 0 ..< allItems.count` or `for plan in allItems.indices` instead.

Comment: better to use the collection `indices` property or simply `for item in allItems {`. Btw UserDefaults has a method called `stringArray(for:)` no need to cast

Comment: In your post plan will be an integer instead of a string. OP is printing the index not the element

Comment: Thanks Gereon, I was not creating the array that was the issue. Also @LeoDabus you were correct as well, I was printing the index, that was another issue.